# Upgraded to RichFaces 4 and lost asynchronous ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

In JSF 1.2 with RichFaces 3.3.3, this code snippet would launch a long-running ajax call on a separate queue so that users could continue working while it executed. But with the upgrade to JSF 2 and RichFaces 4, all queues are mapped back to a single JSF queue and therefore everything grinds to a halt until this query is complete.

I would settle for a way to just launch the ajax call and manage my own delayed updates, but the queue is totally blocked until this call returns. I've tried using jQuery ajax primitives to bypass the JSF queue but wow.. creating your own JSF ajax call from scratch just isn't worth it. Does anyone have a workaround for the missing asynchronous ajax queues in JSF 2+?

```
        <a4j:jsFunction name="myFunction" action="#{bean.longRunningMethod}" 
                    render="myDataPanelUsingTheResults"
                    execute="@this">            
        <a4j:attachQueue name="secondQueue"/>  
     </a4j:jsFunction>
```